# Hot to create subscribstion text that is according to new google policy from GoogleBillingItem dynamically?

Tags: android, google-play

My update was rejected because, according to Google, I didn't include all the required information. However, that information is actually visible to the user after they click on subscribe button in google play library UI isnt it. So htere is complete terms visible to user and we need to somehow duplicate this text in UI of the app itself to for user to see it later again.

So Google wants me to include static text there that is copy of that later visible here donw [image: Google play UI with terms] or maybe because the subscription terms can be changed in the Google Play Console so it should be dynamic isnt it ?

So I believe this is text they want us developers to place and duplicate inside of application UI ?

> You'll be charged €5.99 automatically every month until you cancel.
> Your price may change as described in the Google Play Terms of
> Service. Learn how to cancel Your refund and 14 day withdrawal rights
> vary by product type: Google Play Terms of Service and Refund Policy.

Should I load the terms from the GoogleBillingItem data and generate subscription text acordingly ?  Is there some API available for that ? I've seen some information about tokens and IDs in GoogleBillingItem and some other complex structire but what we need is just that text that is according to google rules whartever they are.

Also if text of terms is not dynamically generated it could be outdated in older versions of apps if I just put there now static text of term that is displayed after you start purchase flow.

How to create the complete subscription term text from the GoogleBillingItem to ensure my app doesn't get rejected again and in future updates if I ever change terms of subscription ? Or how to get it somehow from google play api so I dont have to generate it programatically in the code of my application ?